# search only whole words in tkinter text widget

Tags: python, python-3.x, search, tkinter

I try to search for Python keywords (print, for, if, while....) in tkinter Tetx widget, but my code found both keywords and words, which contains keywords and i have to eliminate this words. Thanks for help.
My code:

```
import tkinter as Tk
def search(word):
try:
    pos = t.search(word,"insert", stopindex="end")
    col, line = pos.split(".")
except ValueError:
    print("all")
else:
    print(pos)
    t.mark_set("insert","%i.%i"%(int(col),int(int(line)+len(word))))
    search(word)
main=Tk.Tk()
t = Tk.Text(main)
t.pack()
t.insert("insert","word in tkinter")
t.mark_set("insert","1.0")
search("in")
main.mainloop()
```

Comment: One very simple solution would be to change "in" to " in "

Comment: searching for the word with surrounded with spaces will fail at the beginning of end of lines. I think regular expressions are the way to go with this

Comment: Do you know what regular expressions are? Are you aware you can use regular expressions to search the text widget?